# MysqlDataTruncation exception in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, utf-8, truncation

In my Spring Boot project, I have set data source URL as follows.

> spring.datasource.url =
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf-8

However when I'm trying to post a comment which contains emojis, the following error is thrown.

`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x82\xF0\x9F...' for column 'content' at row 1`

I could find lot of answers regarding this, but none of were helpful for me.

**Comment.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment extends DateAudit{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  @JsonIgnore
  private User createdBy;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", nullable = false)
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Task task;

  @Lob 
  private String content;

  public Comment() {

  }

  //getters and setters

}
```